# $HOMEPATH + \ not working in GitBash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, git-bash

I'm trying to create a script that can be used by all by all users.

I am using GitBash on a Windows 7 machine and the line which I am trying to automate is

```
alias proxyon="source $HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh
```

Now the issue with this is,

```
echo &HOMEPATH
\Users\<username>
```

GitBash, when executing removes the \ as it's a special charecter, so when I try to run the command "proxyon", it error's with

```
sh.exe": Users<username>/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh: no such file or directory found
```

Is there any way around this? As I can't change the $HOMEPATH, as it has a unique identifier, so it couldn't be a universal script.

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: GitHub? GitHub doesn't provide shell access. I guess you mean git bash. Next, you are supposed to replace `<username>` with the actual username. `<username>` doesn't expand to anything. `~username` will expand to the user's home, if you are using bash.

Comment: `<username>` is a placeholder here I believe.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I did mean GitBash as mentioned in the first sentence. Not sure why I decided to use GitHub the second time, guess it's on the mind!

Also, Etan is right, <username> is the placeholder, wanted to remove it, just to be safe. I guess I should have made this clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the value of that variable is being expanded at the time the `proxyon` alias is being created and then the literal string with the backslashes is being unescaped *again* when the alias runs.

You need to prevent one of those unescapes from happening.

If you want the value of `$HOMEPATH` that exists when `proxyon` is executed to be used (as opposed to the value of `$HOMEPATH` that exists when the alias is created) then switch the double quotes to single quotes on the `alias` creation.

```
alias proxyon='source $HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh'
```

You should quote the variable expansion when used anyway so this should really be:

```
alias proxyon='source "$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh"'
```

If you want the value of `$HOMEPATH` that exists when the alias is created to be used (as opposed to the value of `$HOMEPATH` that exists when the alias is run) then you want to add escaped double quotes to the alias creation.

```
alias proxyon="source \"$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh\""
```

Comment: Hi Etan, Thanks for the explanation :) The 3rd command seems to do the trick.

Just to develop this a little further, as part of the .sh script, it expects On or Off to be inputted. So as an example

alias proxyon="source $AWS_TOOLS_PATH/proxy-switch.sh on"

Where would the "on" or "off" fit in to the 3rd command?

Comment: All three of those should work. Of the three the third is the one I think *least* likely to be what you actually want. What if, for some reason, `$HOMEPATH` changes after the alias is created? Do you want the original `$HOMEPATH` value to be used or the new one? I would imagine the new one (which requires the second (or first) version).

Comment: Arguments to the sourced script go between the ending inner quote and the ending outer quote. The inner quotes keep the file path as a single word. The outer quotes keep the entire command as a single word for the `alias` command. So arguments need to go *outside* the script path but inside the right-hand side of the alias.

Comment: You are right, not sure where I went wrong when copying the 1st and 2nd command but it has worked now

alias proxyon='source $HOMEPATH/.proxy.proxy-switch.sh on'

The above seems to do the trick.

Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Use the second one with the double quotes. You almost *always* want to double quote variable expansions.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. But I tried to move the code into a Powershell script and run it from there, so...

dd-content "${env:homepath}\.proxy\TempProxy.bat" "alias proxyon='source "$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh on"'

But I get

The string starting:
At C:\Chef\windowsdevbox-master\test.ps1:2 char:111
+ add-content "${env:homepath}\.proxy\TempProxy.bat" "alias proxyon='source "$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh on <<<< "'
is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\Chef\windowsdevbox-master\test.ps1:3 char:1

Comment: If you are going to stick a double-quoted string inside another double-quoted string you probably need to escape the internal double-quotes. That being said that alias line isn't a batch command so putting it in a `.bat` file seems a little odd to me.

Comment: I guess to add a little bit of background, as if you can't tell, I'm new to all of this ;). I'm trying to put a "starter script" together, it installs everything through chocolatey. Then the end bit is to do some configuration changes.

The bit I'm trying to do now is to create a file (The bat file), which is ran every time someone starts up GitBash, then they can use the ProxyOn, ProxyOff command. That being said, maybe .bat is the wrong type

Comment: File extensions aren't "types" in any way other than for the default execution that the Windows shell does. But yes, linux shell scripts are generally given `.sh` extensions where Windows batch scripts are generally given `.bat` extensions.

Comment: On Windows, shell scripts are given .sh extensions. On Linux, giving executables (including shell scripts with the executable bit set) any extension at all is bad form (though many people do so regardless). See https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful.shtml for background.

Comment: Understood. Sorry, I did want to move this to chat but, sadly I don't have the reputation for it.

I took your advice and removed the internal ". It worked in the sense that it  did copy some text across to the file however, it didn't copy the contents of the $HOMEPATH, it copied nothing at all, so it just looked like "alias proxyon='source /.proxy/proxy-switch.sh on" So I presume without the " marks, it won't read the contents of $HOMEPATH correctly.

Comment: No, that's just being expanded by powershell at that point most likely. You didn't want to remove the inner quotes you wanted to escape them (`\"` or whatever the appropriate powershell escape is `~` or something I think) like in the example I gave for double-quotes inside double-quotes. Similarly you are going to need to escape the `$` in `$HOMEPATH` from powershell there.

Comment: So the escape char for powershell is `. I tried it in a varierty places, basing it off the information which you gave above and i didn't have much luck. When I tried "alias proxyon='source `"$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh on"`'" it didn't error but, it didn't paste the contents of $HOMEPATH. When I tried "alias proxyon='source `"$HOMEPATH/.proxy/proxy-switch.sh on`"'" I got an error. I'm pretty sure this is something I'm doing wrong.... but trying my best to understand it.

Comment: I think you should probably ask a new question based on this one about the embedding in the powershell script issue. Mostly just so you have somewhere to document (with sane formatting) the things you've tried and what you've gotten for each case.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help and patience on this :). I've posted another question, as suggested, at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920934/embedding-in-the-powershell-script-issue